# regExp: get everything between opening bracket '(' and closing bracket ')'

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following regular Expression: **/prefix(([^)]+))/g**

This expression matches everything between **'prefix('** and **')'**.

For example:

```
value = 'prefix(foo) bar(foo)';

return value.match( /prefix\(([^)]+)\)/g )
```

result: 'prefix(foo)'

---

What I am trying to achieve is this:

```
value = 'prefix() bar(foo)';

return value.match( correctRegularExpression )
```

result: 'prefix()'

---

I am searching for **correctRegularExpression** and I am really stuck here since I am new to regular Expressions.

Comment: Use: `/prefix\(([^)]*)\)/g`

Comment: Or `return value.match(/prefix\(.*?\)/g)`. It looks like what is inside the parentheses is not used, so there is no need using the capturing group.

Comment: Better yet, if these might be nested: `/prefix\([^()]*\)/`

Answer (score 0):

Use capture groups in your regex like so:

```js
var value = 'prefix(hello) foo(goodbye)';

var matches = value.match(/prefix\((\w*)\)/);

console.log(matches[1]);
```

Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match